# How to close a SQlite database from javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am connecting to the browser SQLite using JavaScript, the website is an real time ajax monitoring system so, it is reading, writing and opening new database connections all the time. and today I got this error in the chrome console:

[image]

It seems I have too many connections to this database and I should close them, but I don't know how to do it.

This is how I usually open a connection:

```
var db = openDatabase("BD_form", "1.0", "Address Book", 200000);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM `myTable`;",[],function(){
        // code for success
    },function(tx, error){
        // code for failure
    });
}
```

Is there something like `db.closeDatabase()` or similar?

Comment: Have you tried `db.close()`?

Comment: It depends on what library you're using - you haven't specified.  [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3), for example, has an explicit `db.close()`.